# Weird 404 errors recorded in Google Analytics; mentions doubleclick and DARTiframe

Tags: google-analytics, http-status-code-404, analytics, adsense

I started a website and everything's going very well. But on Analytics, I'm seeing a weird 404 URLs on the Behavior tab. I am using AdSense and nRelate to serve ads.

I am seeing these URL's in Google Analytics:

```
/404.html?page=/doubleclick/DARTIframe.html?gtVersion=200_41&mediaserver=http://s0.2mdn.net/879366&xpc={"cn":"peerIframe58527422","tp":null,"osh":null,"pru":"http://sdherald.com/doubleclick/DARTIframe.html?gtVersion=relay_200_41&mediaserver=http://s0.2mdn.net/879366","ppu":"http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/robots.txt","lpu":"http://sdherald.com/robots.txt"}&from=http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-8282582681724773&format=300x250&output=html&h=250&slotname=3724546046&adk=672603818&w=300&lmt=1404675131&flash=0&url=http://sdherald.com/life-hacks-vinegar/?f=f&dt=1404653529944&bpp=1184&shv=r20140630&cbv=r20140417&saldr=aa&prev_fmts=320x50,300x250_as&correlator=1404653530086&frm=20&ga_vid=1386066698.1404653530&ga_sid=1404653530&ga_hid=481051372&ga_fc=1&ga_wpids=UA-52432983-1&u_tz=-360&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=480&u_w=320&u_ah=460&u_aw=320&u_cd=32&u_nplug=1&u_nmime=34&dff=open sans&dfs=14&adx=10&ady=2614&biw=320&bih=372&eid=317150304&oid=3&ref=https://m.facebook.com&rx=0&eae=0&fc=3&vis=1&abl=CS&ppjl=d&fu=256&ifi=3&xpc=uwbOj59GAe&p=http://sdherald.com&dtd=1212

/404.html?page=/doubleclick/DARTIframe.html?gtVersion=200_41&mediaserver=http://s0.2mdn.net/879366&xpc={"cn":"peerIframe58527753","tp":null,"osh":null,"pru":"http://sdherald.com/doubleclick/DARTIframe.html?gtVersion=relay_200_41&mediaserver=http://s0.2mdn.net/879366","ppu":"http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/robots.txt","lpu":"http://sdherald.com/robots.txt"}&from=http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-8282582681724773&format=728x90&output=html&h=90&slotname=6318085641&adk=3863123026&w=728&lmt=1404672595&flash=0&url=http://sdherald.com/life-hacks-vinegar/?f=f&dt=1404654595455&bpp=24&shv=r20140630&cbv=r20140417&saldr=aa&correlator=1404654595852&frm=20&ga_vid=1756553763.1404654595&ga_sid=1404654595&ga_hid=1419792073&ga_fc=1&ga_wpids=UA-52432983-1&u_tz=-300&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=1024&u_w=768&u_ah=1024&u_aw=748&u_cd=32&u_nplug=1&u_nmime=34&dff=open sans&dfs=14&adx=148&ady=62&biw=1024&bih=704&eid=317150304&oid=3&ref=https://m.facebook.com&rx=0&eae=0&vis=1&abl=CS&ppjl=u&fu=256&ifi=1&xpc=GFXZzfrZT6&p=http://sdherald.com&dtd=424
```

I have no idea what these are and where they came from.. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Please help me.

The website URL is http://sdherald.com.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `404` for `DARTIframe.html`, then you will probably want to get that file from Google and upload it to your server.

**[DoubleClick Rich Media iframe solution](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/156583)**

> To enable iframe access for DoubleClick Rich Media ads, a publisher
>   must put a special file on their domain that acts as a *bridge* between
>   the ad server domain and the publisher domain.
>
> DoubleClick Rich Media requires that the publisher add the
>   `DARTIframe.html` file to a specific relative URL `/doubleclick` folder at
>   the root directory of the web service on their webservers. For
>   example, if your website is `www.example.com`, put the `DARTIframe.html`
>   file into `www.example.com/doubleclick`.

Comment: This looks like the solution, although I will have to see if I get any more 404 errors like that for a few days.